# Error associating dependecies betwen EJB and PersistenceUnity on JBoss 7

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, hsqldb

I am having problems while starting EJB application on AS JBOSS 7 or on EAP 6.1 with JBoss AS 7.2 while associating dependencies between EJB and persistenceUnit.

Line log error:

> 10:07:04,857 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.ClienteDAOBean.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/em\" ]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"crm.war#crmUnity\" missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources/CRMDS ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".jndiDependencyService missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ClienteDAOBean/em\", jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/em\" ]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"crm.war\".component.br/com/crm/model/dao/ContatoDAORemote.START missing [ jboss.naming.context.java.module.crm.crm.\"env/br.com.crm.model.dao.ContatoDAOBean/em\" ]"]}}}

Below, follow xml files and EJB code:

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems,Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/application_1_2.dtd">
<application>
    <display-name>crm</display-name>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>crm.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>crm</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <module>
        <ejb>crmEJB.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

crm-ds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The Hypersonic embedded database JCA connection factory config
$Id: hsqldb-ds.xml,v 1.1.2.11 2003/09/28 12:31:36 starksm Exp $ -->
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource enabled="true" 
     use-java-context="true" pool-name="CRMDS">
         <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/CRMDS</jndi-name>
         <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:database/crm</connection-url>
         <driver>hsqldb.jar</driver>
         <driver-class>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver-class>
         <user-name>SA</user-name>
         <password></password>
    </local-tx-datasource>
 </datasources>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="crmUnity" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/CRMDS</jta-data-source>  
      <class>br.com.crm.model.entities.Cliente</class>
      <class>br.com.crm.model.entities.Contato</class>
      <properties>  
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />  
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />  
      </properties>  
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

ContatoDAOBeanRemote.java

```
@Remote
public interface ContatoDAORemote {

  // code
}
```

ContatoDAOBean.java

```
package br.com.crm.model.dao;

/**
 * @author tarcisio
 * Session Bean controlado pelo Container para realização de operações sobre
 * a base de dados de contatos de clientes.
 */
@Stateless(name = "br/com/crm/model/dao/ContatoDAORemote")
public class ContatoDAOBean implements ContatoDAORemote{

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "crmUnity")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf; 

    // code


}
```

standalone.xml

```
<!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright 2011, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
  ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
  ~
  ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
  ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
  ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
  ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
  ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
  -->

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.0">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web" />
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld" />
    </extensions>

    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="PropertiesMgmtSecurityRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" />
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
           <native-interface interface="management" port="9999" />
           <http-interface interface="management" port="9990"/>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>

            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>

            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="H2DS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <pool></pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation></validation>
                    <timeout></timeout>
                    <statement></statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.0">
            <deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="deployments" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.0" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="false" />
            <bean-validation enabled="false" />
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads blocking="true">
                <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads blocking="true">
                        <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.0">
            <jmx-connector registry-binding="jmx-connector-registry" server-binding="jmx-connector-server" />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.0" activation="lazy">
            <configuration pid="org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager">
                <property name="manager.root">jboss-osgi</property>
            </configuration>
            <properties>
                <!--
                    A comma seperated list of module identifiers. Each system module
                    is added as a dependency to the OSGi framework module. The packages
                    from these system modules can be made visible as framework system packages.
                    http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA
                -->
                <property name="org.jboss.osgi.system.modules">
                org.apache.commons.logging,
                org.apache.log4j,
                org.jboss.as.osgi,
                org.slf4j,
                </property>
                <!--
                    Framework environment property identifying extra packages which the system bundle
                    must export from the current execution environment
                -->
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra">
                org.apache.commons.logging;version=1.1.1,
                org.apache.log4j;version=1.2,
                org.jboss.as.osgi.service;version=7.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.deployment.interceptor;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.spi.capability;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.spi.util;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.testing;version=1.0,
                org.jboss.osgi.vfs;version=1.0,
                org.slf4j;version=1.5.10,
                </property>
                <!-- Specifies the beginning start level of the framework -->
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">1</property>
            </properties>
            <modules>
                <!-- modules registered with the OSGi layer on startup -->
                <module identifier="javaee.api"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.logging"/>
                <!-- bundles installed on startup -->
                <module identifier="org.apache.aries.util"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.webconsole"/>
                <module identifier="org.osgi.compendium"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 1 -->
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 2 -->
                <module identifier="org.apache.aries.jmx" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.eventadmin" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.metatype" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.scr" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.apache.felix.webconsole" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.jmx" startlevel="2"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.http" startlevel="2"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 3 -->
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.blueprint" startlevel="3"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.webapp" startlevel="3"/>
                <module identifier="org.jboss.osgi.xerces" startlevel="3"/>
            </modules>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0" />
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.0">
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid />
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0" default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <connector name="http" scheme="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
               <alias name="localhost" />
               <alias name="example.com" />
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0" />
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
           <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-registry" port="1090"/>
        <socket-binding name="jmx-connector-server" port="1091"/>
        <socket-binding name="jndi" port="1099"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

Project Technologies:

Embedded HSQDB database version 2.2.3

EJB 3

JPA 2.1

HIBERNATE 3 providing JPA Persistence

Can anybody help me to solve this dependencies problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you forgot to make DataSource settings in JBoss? Can you show datasorce definition from your standalone.xml

Comment: I posted now the standalone.xml. I need set my database in a file inside my ear application and not in memory of JBoss. Look at my crm-ds.xml above, setting for this objective. I think that to use database inside the application, does not changes standalone.xml, or am I mistaken? @AlexanderFedyukov

Comment: I'm not sure about your crm, but suppose that JPA provider can't found Datasource definition, which may defined in persistence.xml or in standard.xml. Unfortunally, I don't know how crm interacts with JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

It would be perfect, if you would place alias for datasource in ear, and config them in standalone.xml: you got database independent distributive in ideal case. Try to insert this block in standalone.xml (I took parameters from your crm-ds.xml):

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/CRMDS" pool-name="CRMDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:database/crm</connection-url>
                <driver-class>org.h2.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>SA</user-name>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Version of subsystem may be server specific.

Comment: How to do this configuration in standard.xml? Where is there standard.xml file?@Alexander Fedyukov

Comment: Sorry, replaced standard.xml with standalone.xml

Comment: Do you know any ant build file that makes this config for me, i.e. , put my datasource in standalone.xml before deploy the application.@Alexander Fedyukov

Comment: On my mind you are choosing wrong way, when trying to configure server settings through ant. In perfect case distributive of application not knows anything about application server setting, except alias to data source. Alias to data source must be written independent from application.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, it's more interesting put the database inside the EAR Project instead in the WAR. But this is task difficult due the poorer documentation about HSQLDB, Hypersonic Database. The properties of persitence.xml file are diffuse. To work fine seems to need magic! @Alexander Fedyukov